# Vue-plugin - Not being able to import local linked custom plugin node module in another project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I created a very basic vue-plugin with some component that will be used in another project. The plugin code can be found [here](https://github.com/indusbull/vue-testplugin). The plugin works fine when tested independently.

In order to use this plugin in another project, I build the plug-in code with

> vue-cli-service build --target lib --name testplugin ./src/index.js

This plugin will never be published to NPM registry and will be used only internally. So to test plugin module in another project, I run `npm link` on plugin dir and then `npm link testplugin` in another project.

Then I use it in another project like below -

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
import { testplugin } from 'testplugin'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

console.log(testplugin)

Vue.use(testplugin, {  })
Vue.use(VueRouter)

new Vue({
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App),  
}).$mount('#app')
```

The project compiles fine but testplugin is undefined. When I check node_modules directory, I can see my testplugin symlinked there.

I have tried diff approaches with no success. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: were you able to figure out the problem? I m facing the same issue

Comment: I was not able to figure this out.

Comment: I figured what my problem was. Not sure if it helps you or not but in my case: in my `vuetify.js` I had `import Vuetify from ./lib/vuetify` and when I changed it to `import Vuetify from vuetify` then it was solved. I had to get vuetify form npm